# Json Array object to string logic

Tags: javascript, jquery

Not sure if I'm repeating the question or concept.

How do I convert the below sample to the below string format  (may not be correct JSON format)

```
[{ "Name":"Test1","check":"true},{ "Name":"Test2","check":"true},{ "Name":"Test3","check":"false"}]
```

string format with appending - for false

Expected o/p:

```
"Test1","Test2","-Test3"
```

I have tried concatenating, but it always ends up with

```
"Test1,Test2-Test3"
```

But I am looking  for 3 separate string separated by comma. Any hint would help

Comment: Use array, `push` elements in it

Comment: `may not be correct json format` test here http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Can you post the code you have already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply iterate through your array and collect the object in your required format:

```js
var obj = [{
        "Name" : "Test1",
        "check" : true
    }, {
        "Name" : "Test2",
        "check" : true
    }, {
        "Name" : "Test3",
        "check" : false
    }
];
  
var result = obj.map(function(x) {
  return x.check ? x.Name : "-" + x.Name;
});

document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result);
```

Note that I have changed the format of your JSON in order to make it valid.

Just in case if you actually have a string `true` and `false`, and you can't change this, you can simply compare it as a string:

```js
var obj = [{
        "Name" : "Test1",
        "check" : "true"
    }, {
        "Name" : "Test2",
        "check" : "true"
    }, {
        "Name" : "Test3",
        "check" : "false"
    }
];

var result = obj.map(function(x) {
  return x.check === 'true' ? x.Name : "-" + x.Name;
});

document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result);
```

Comment: It looks like `x.check` is a string in OP, not boolean

Comment: Thank you !! Super speed..from here i can take it to my logic..ll mark answer.Thanks

Comment: @Yeldar am getting the  stringify format from server API. Is there a way i can update it to the format like your first recommend one?

Comment: @Tharun If it is a third-party API and you have to use it, then just use the second approach. You can do nothing with a mistake of anothers :)

Comment: @Tharun You can check the update. I have changed the usage of `forEach` to `map` in order to make it even shorter :)

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev we are developing the API in .net. i usually get that way. Is there a way i can set in API to get the correct   format?

Comment: That's absolutely another question. I will be happy to answer it, but, first, you need to try it yourself. Then, if you don't find an answer yourself or in the Internet, come here again and ask a new question :)

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev tried but did not make it work :( will post another question

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div id="output"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var obj = [{
        "Name" : "Test1",
        "check" : true
    }, {
        "Name" : "Test2",
        "check" : true
    }, {
        "Name" : "Test3",
        "check" : false
    }
];

function getNames(){
    var length=obj.length;
  //  alert(length);
    var op=[];
    for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++){
     //   alert(obj[i].Name);
        op[i]='"'+obj[i].Name+'"';
    }
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=op;
}

getNames();
```

Your output is there as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through the valid JSON array(obj) and append the required values(obj.Name) to the empty string(str) based on the condition(appending '-' for 'false' value of obj.check).

```
var obj = [{
        "Name" : "Test1",
        "check" : true
    }, {
        "Name" : "Test2",
        "check" : true
    }, {
        "Name" : "Test3",
        "check" : false
    }
];

var str = '';
for(var x in obj){
    str += (obj[x].check === true) ? obj[x].Name : '-'+obj[x].Name;
    str += (x != (obj.length-1)) ? ',' : '';
}

alert(str);
```